# Jcrop + Canvas Transparent Image Issue On Crop

Tags: javascript, jcrop

Currently we are using ONLY Javascript + jQuery on our project and we are trying to convert out final image from jCrop to a base64 to be passed to a third party service with the help of HTML canvas. So far we have everything figured out expect one piece. When a user uploads a transparent PNG to jCrop, we crop the image and in the canvas preview, the transparent part of the image gets blurred when moving or expanding the jCrop select.

You can see the example of the problem here and you can see that when I was dragging the select in jCrop the transparent part of the image blurred badly: http://i46.tinypic.com/23jl946.png

I've played with some opacity settings in jCrop like:

```
bgColor: 'transparent'
```

And tried globalAlpha for canvas but these don't seem to work.

```
var c           = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.globalAlpha   = 0;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually just using canvas's clearRect fixed it.

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```